# Полная катушка

Tags: фразеология

Когда хотят сказать, что что-то делается полным ходом, либо какой-то процесс развернут, как говорят, в народе "во всю ивановскую", то зачастую употребляют выражение "на полную катушку".
А вот мне стало интересно, о какой катушке идет речь (почему-то сразу подумалось об индукционной))) и при чем тут, собственно, она?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О, здесь много разных версий. Выражение довольно новое (в словарях В. И. Даля и Д. Н. Ушакова не упоминается).

1. gramota.ru говорит, что выражение - от регулирования громкости звучания радиоаппарата: регулятор громкости по форме напоминает катушку.
2. выражение пошло от старой мальчишеской игрушки. В деревянную катушку из - под ниток с торца вбивались два маленьких гвоздика без шляпок, на них насаживался жестяной пропеллер. Дёргая со всей силы за верёвочку, намотанную на катушку, дети запускали пропеллер высоко в воздух.
3. dslov.narod.ru утверждает, что его источник - речь рыболовов: леска разматывается с катушки. Когда ловят рыбу на спиннинг, то выброс крючка на всю длину лески (катушка с леской полностью разматывается) означает, что рыбак делает все возможное для ловли рыбы.
4. Выражение вошло в современную речь из языка связистов во время Великой Отечественной войны, а затем расширило свое значение.

Выбирайте на Ваш вкус.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно только, если понять, что как только изобрели электричество, сразу начали делать провода, которые наматываются на катушку. Проложить линию, хоть по земле(в траншее), хоть на столбах по воздуху, труд один из самых тяжелых, и чем больше энергии по проводам передается, тем больше эти самые катушки с проводами и толще провод. А провода нужны были в массовом количестве для  электрификации  и шло это как раз   полным ходом в начале 20-века. Был даже план в России-ГОЭЛРО, который был реализован в самые короткие сроки, что привело к резкому скачку в промышленности. С момента появления радио в стране, а это уже было после реализации плана электрофикации, сопротивления переменные уже не делали в виде соленоидов, по которым двигали рычажок, они были компактные и в корпусе. Так что на всю катушку, это если в школе только физические опыты делали, на всю катушку длины реостата движком ток регулировали. В "грамоте.ру" запечатлелся второй вариант, с опытами, которые на радио перенесли, из далекого прошлого 19 века, когда все электричество регулировалось катушечными реостатами.
Спиннингисты никогда до полного катушку не разматывают, иначе блесна после остановки назад летит, связисты всегда берут провода с запасом солидным, и там и там запас должен быть. А игрушка и есть игрушка, тем более такая, без массового применения, ну просто никак в язык.
А вот реостат--он даже в трамваях был.
http://im1-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=188e413eb3f90882291fe1b85aba33ed-51-144&n=21